# Can I use Iterator on Collections to get an element in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator

I am studying about `Collections` and a question starts automatically...

I learned that on an `ArrayList` I can use the methods `add()` and `remove()` on the elements; but now I am reading that there is another way, it is to use the object `Iterator` with its methods.

So can I have the freedom to choose the methods from `Iterator` rather from `ArrayList`? 
If yes, there are pros and cons?

I read:
1) Ask a Collection to hand you an Iterator using a method called `iterator()`. That Iterator is ready to return the first element in the sequence.
2)Get the next object sequence with `next()`;
3)See if there any more objects in the sequence with `hasNext()`;
4)Remove the last element returned by iterator with `remove()`;

Comment: Yeah you can't, I'd rather use enhanced `for` (`foreach` equivalent of C# ) to add or remove stuff.

Comment: @alfasin Sure you can use iterator to add element to a list: [`listIterator.add(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add-E-)

Comment: What do you want to do? Please share the code you have now.

Comment: update the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterator is a relatively old construct to iterate through the elements utilising the internal structure (which is more optimal than an external loop).

Sometimes Iterator allows more:

```
for (Car car : cars) {
    if (car.diesel) {
        cars.remove(car); // ERROR while looping cars one cannot alter it.
    }
}

for (Iterator<Car> iter = cars.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Car car = iter.next();
    if (car.diesel) {
        iter.remove(); // FINE
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); ++i) {
    Car car = cars.get(i); // Could be slow for a LinkedList
    if (car.diesel) {
        cars.remove(i); // FINE
        --i; // So we do not skip the next, now at index i.
    }
}
```

And java 8 now has **streams**, but which is another (very nice) approach to collections.

Comment: So, do you confirm my words?

Comment: Iterator primarily is for walking through a collection. The ListIterator is more like a cursor on the List. Iterator is more typing than for-each (`for :`) but allows to alter the collection inside the loop. So I would go for for-each whenever possible. Though, yes you seem to have grasped the mechanisms. By the way java 8 streams process collections perfectly.